# Add category page effects on homepage in Magento

Tags: magento, infinite-scroll, magento-1.7

in `Magento 1.7` I have added Infinite scroll effect on my category page using this effect  http://demo.rapidcommerce.eu/default/catalogsearch/result/?q=the#/page/3.

Now I want to add the effect on my Homepage. I am displaying all products on my homepage using the below code in cms-> pages->Home->custom layout in admin Panel.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    </block>
</reference>
```

This displays all categories on my homepage.
I want to add http://demo.rapidcommerce.eu/default/catalogsearch/result/?q=the#/page/3 on Homepage. as I am new in Magento. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I only want infinite scroll effect on my home page which is showing all  products,Experts help me out